# Text field to Hidden field value - value not being set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue with passing hidden values. I have a search field that onclick calls my javascript function with the intention of setting a hidden fields value further down the page.

```
    <div class="search">

        <input type="text" name="username" class="mySearch" value="">
        <input type="button" class="myButton" value="" onclick="setSearch();">

    </div>
```

My javascript, `i` is set outside of the function.

```
setSearch(){
    if(i == 0){
        $('input:hidden[name="search1"]').val($(".mySearch").val()); 
    }
    else if(i == 1)
    {
        $('input:hidden[name="search2"]').val($(".mySearch").val()); 
    }
    i++;
}
```

and then the field I'm try to set

```
<div class="sendallHolder">
    <form method="post" action="getTweets.php">

        <input type="hidden" name="fromTest" id="fromTest"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="untilTest" id="untilTest"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="latTest" id="latTest"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="longTest" id="longTest"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="search1" id="search1" />
        <input type="hidden" name="search2" id="search2" />


        <input type="submit" class="sendAll" value="Gather News!">
    </form>

</div>
```

It runs through the loop twice but each time its not setting the values properly in my hidden fields. the dev tools in chrome tell me that the 'value' is popping up but no value is being set. I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: why don't you just get your hiddens by id selectors? $('#search1').val($(".mySearch").val()) and $('#search2').val($(".mySearch").val())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:hidden` selector doesn't do what you think. It matches elements that have been hidden using CSS, it doesn't match `type="hidden"` inputs. Just use

```
$("#search1")
```

since you have an `id` on the elements.

Comment: I had this before, I've just re entered it to test again after a reading over these. Tbh the :hidden field was a bit of desperation at trying to figure it out.

I've put it back to what I had now which is $('#search1').val($(".mySearch").val())

The value still doesn't seem to be passing.

Whats the best way to set an alert to print what the value of search1 and search2 are now?

Comment: `alert($("#search1").val())`

Comment: Make sure you don't have duplicate IDs.

Comment: Tried it, getting the alert but no value. Really strange and there is no duplicates.

Comment: Found it. It was a duplicate. What a bother. Thank you very much Barmar:)! It was probably that all along, thats coding for you though I guess! haha

Answer (score 3):

Use hidden input ID like this :

```
$('#search1').val($(".mySearch").val())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mySearch").keyup(addhjc);
function addhjc(){
        $('#search2').val($(".mySearch").val());
}
```

or

```
$('.myButton').click(function(){   
        $('#search2').val($(".mySearch").val()); 
});
```

also

```
function setSearch(){
    if(i === 0){........
```

and define `i` `var`